# Double exponential Taylor series $\exp(-\exp(k-ex))$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity, tetration, power-towers

k is real constant $\gt = 1$.  Is $a_n$ for $f(x)$ positive, increasing, and $\lt 1$, where $n\lt= e^{k-1}$?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \exp(-\exp(k-ex))$$

$f(x)$ is the double exponential as described.  Prove the conjecture that the Taylor series coefficients for f(x) are positive, increasing, and all less than 1, up to $a_n$, where $n\lt= e^{k-1}$, and also probably for ceiling as well, $n \lt= \lceil e^{k-1}\rceil$.  The first two or three terms above n are still increasing in magnitude and positive, but the Taylor series coefficients become chaotic, and soon have both negative and positive values.

For example, consider k=3, where $f(0)=\exp(-\exp(3))$, where $f(x)$ has the following Taylor series.  The first negative term is $a_{12}$.  $\lceil e^{k-1}\rceil = 8$.  The first term>=1 is $a_9$.

```
k3=     0.00000000189217869484
+x^ 1*  0.000000103309456270
+x^ 2*  0.00000267984048780
+x^ 3*  0.0000437878433105
+x^ 4*  0.000503376203252
+x^ 5*  0.00430132652897
+x^ 6*  0.0280820601079
+x^ 7*  0.141245147887
+x^ 8*  0.540609219094
+x^ 9*  1.49907379722
+x^10*  2.54732645227
+x^11*  0.276584318427
+x^12* -11.9671868638
+x^13* -30.4747754691
+x^14* -10.2766978768
```

I derived my conjecture using non-rigorous methods, by finding optimal radii to do a Cauchy circle integral for the various coefficients of a_n, by using the inverse of $ e x \exp(k-ex)$ as a "frequency approximation" guide for what radius to use for the Cauchy integral.  This inverse function has a branch singularity at x=1/e corresponding to where the Taylor series coefficients become chaotic.  I'm hoping someone else can give a more rigorous approach.

I am interested in using these approximations to help rigorously answer a math stack question about a [conjectured nowhere analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675555/show-that-the-iterated-lnn-of-tetrationx-n-is-nowhere-analytic).  The next step is to get an approximation for the "radius of convergence" for each Taylor series coefficient, $\exp(-\ln(a_n)/n)$, for all Taylor series coefficients in the well behaved region, $n\lt= e^{k-1}$.

I have also looked at the chaotic Taylor series coefficients. This is a closely related but possibly more difficult problem.  Consider the Taylor series for  $$f2(x) = \exp(-\exp(k - \frac{\pi x}{2}))$$
Here, we are interested in where the |a_n| reaches its maximum magnitude, but this is more difficult because the Taylor series coefficients are chaotic for n>exp(k-1), from the result above.  This function scales the Taylor series coefficients from $f(x)$ by $(\frac{\pi}{2e})^n$.  The second conjecture is that |a_m| reaches a maximum near $m \approx 0.5\pi e^k$, where $a_m \approx r^m$, where r approaches 1 as k increases.  For the k=3 example, the maximum magnitude of $a_m$ occurs near n=31.  This is also the minimum for the radius of convergence approximation, $\exp(-\ln(a_n)/n)$.

If we consider k=10 for $f(x)$ than $n=\lceil e^9 \rceil = 8104$. The first conjecture would be that all Taylor series coefficients are positive up that point. This would also hold for $f2(x)$.  For $f2(x)$ for k=10, we would expect the Taylor series coefficients to peak in magnitude near $m \approx 0.5\pi e^{10} \approx 34599$. These numbers quickly become too large to actually compute the Taylor series coefficients by brute force, which is what makes these approximations useful.  In the problem I mentioned, I have used approximations for the radius of convergence for k in the millions, far beyond what can be computed.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\expo{-\expo{k - \expo{}x}}&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\expo{k - \expo{}x}}^{\ell} \over \ell!}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\expo{k}}^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,
\expo{-\ell\expo{}x}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\expo{k}}^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,
\sum_{\ell'=0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ell\expo{}x}^{\ell'} \over \ell'!}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\expo{k}}^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,
\sum_{\ell'=0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ell\expo{}}^{\ell'}x^{\ell'} \over \ell'!}
=\sum_{\ell'=0}^{\infty}x^{\ell'}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{\ell'} \over \ell'!}%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\expo{k}}^{\ell}\ell^{\ell'} \over \ell!}\,}
\end{align}

> $$
> \expo{-\expo{k - \expo{}x}}=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\,,\qquad
> a_{n}\equiv {\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\,\expo{-\expo{k}}B_{n}\pars{-\expo{k}}
> $$
>   where $B_{n}\pars{x}$ is the
>   [Bell Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html).
>   Also [See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Comment: Thanks Felix!  I thought about pursuing Bell polyomials, but I hadn't done it yet.  I got your Bell polynomials implemented; and I think your formula has a small typo, missing a factor of $e^n$, but if I map $a_n \mapsto a_n\times e^n$, then I get the same polynomial I posted for k=3 (which I generated with pari-gp).  I don't know how to use the Bell polynomials to prove the pattern holds, for increasing values of k, that the Taylor series coefficients increase, and then become chaotic, but I will investigate.